# Javascript navigating between elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get values from different elements on the click event of a 'a' element.
Given the code:

```
<tr data-id="20">
  <div class="row">
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a data-checked="false" class="btn btn-info btn-xs oiCmd-btn oiCmd-btn-paid-toggle">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs oiCmd-btn oiCmd-btn-mod-price">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <span>...</span>
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>$<em class="oiPrice">50.00</em>
    </td>
  </div>
</tr>
```

I need to get the value 50.00 from oiPrice and 20 from data-id in the 'tr' from the click event '.oiCmd-btn-paid-toggle'.
I am at a loss I have tried many things with .parent and .child but I keep getting it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is invalid, tr cannot have div as a child

Then

```
$('.oiCmd-btn-paid-toggle').click(function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var oiPrice = $.trim($tr.find('.oiPrice').text());
    var id = $tr.data('id');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4anBe/)

Comment: Thanks was exactly what I was looking for. and thanks for the hint about the html didn't notice I had left that there.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataId = $("tr").attr("data-id");
```

You can change selector `$("tr")` as your requirements.

```
var oiPrice = $(".oiPrice").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know how the complete code is, this may or may not work in your case.

for 20 from data-id:

```
$("tr[data-id]").attr("id");
```

for 50 from oiPrice:

```
$(".oiPrice").val();
```

you can adjust with .eq(x) if you have many elements.
Hope this helps!